# How to output all taxonomy field values on a node in views?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

How can I display all field values that are on the taxonomy terms that are applied to a given node?

So say I have the following Vocab defined:

Vocab name:Fruit Description:Fruit Categories w/ codes Field: fruit_code

And I add the following terms:

tname:Apple fruit_code:appl
tname:Orange fruit_code:orng
tname:Pine Apple fruit_code:pin_appl

Now.. I can apply a field to my view that will output all the tax termnames associated with the nodes that are returned: ie. "Apple, Orange, Pine Apple"..

But when I add the relationship for tid to the view and then try outputting the fruit_code field.. I get duplicate nodes returned, one for each term applied to the node.  How can I get the fruit_code to oupt in the same manner as the termnames in my view w/o having duplicate nodes displayed??

Comment: I deleted my answer, I totally misread the question.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What is the difference between the term name and fruit_code? Isn't fruit_code just the taxonomy reference field attached to the content type? Adding the field outputs the terms correctly. Why would you need a relationship?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the views distinct mode.

Drupal 7: Query Settings > distinct
Drupal 6: Distinct

Either that or hook into the view and do some extra processing through a custom module.